# Windows 7 remote shutdown: Access denied(5)

Tags: networking, windows-7, cmd, remote-access, shutdown

I am trying to force a remote shutdown from my laptop to my PC:

```
machine> shutdown -m \\192.168.2.10 -s -f -t 0
192.168.2.10: Access denied(5)
```

I am in a WLAN/LAN environment:

- Laptop is in WLAN with IP `192.168.2.100` (DHCP), Win 7 (64 bit)
- PC is connected via LAN `192.168.8.10` (static), Win 7 (32 bit)
- Router IP `192.168.2.1`/Subnetmask `255.255.255.0`

Access to PC is restricted by username and password.

What do I have to change about the command or about the systems configurations - whilst access restrictions have to remain as is?

Comment: do you have a domain set up? and are you wanting to do this using the credentials you are logged in with?

Comment: No domain but workgroup. I want to use the user and pass I am using on my PC - not my laptop credentials.

Comment: requesting to move this question to Superuser instead

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You can use the [NET USE](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/net_use.mspx?mfr=true) command to authenticate on the remote server and then use shutdown.exe

```
NET USE \\MyServer\IPC$ mypassword /USER:myuser
```

http://www.squidworks.net/2011/07/how-to-pass-a-username-and-password-to-windows-shutdown-exe-command/

This does not work with UAC enabled, unless the policy [LocalAccountTokenFilterPolicy](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/951016) is enabled on the remote server.

> When a user who is a member of the local administrators group on the target remote computer establishes a remote administrative connection by using the net use * \remotecomputer\Share$ command, for example, they will not connect as a full administrator. The user has no elevation potential on the remote computer, and the user cannot perform administrative tasks.

Comment: It's basically the server port for the SMB protocol in Windows (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Message_Block#Client-server_approach), which let's you talk to the Windows OS from a different machine.

Comment: It doesn't work... I get "The command completed successfully" from NET USE, the I still get "Access is denied.(5)" from shutdown...

Comment: I found the cause, it's UAC. I had to enable the policy LocalAccountTokenFilterPolicy

Comment: Does one have to enable LocalAccountTokenFilterPolicy on the local or the remote machine?

Comment: @wensveen It's on the remote server. I've added clarification about  LocalAccountTokenFilterPolicy, as well as, a quote from MSDN.

Comment: I was using two windows 10 computers.  I still couldn't shut down the other one, until I found this:  https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/4cd01733-0f21-4078-979d-5080bc0c98fb/remote-shutdown-access-denied-5?forum=w7itprogeneral  I adapted it for Windows 10.  First `RUN secpol.msc`.  Then go to:  `Local Policies->User Rights Assignment` then `Force Shutdown from a remote system`.  Type "Everyone" instead of Administrators, and save.  After doing this I no longer even needed to use login credentials in NET USE.  I can simply call shutdown.

Comment: Note:  the above advice was to be done on the remote computer.

Comment: tuning `LocalAccountTokenFilterPolicy` and using `PsShutdown` works fine for Windows 10 allowing it to be remotely shut down from Windows 7 (using administator account)