# InitiateShutdown fails with RPC_S_SERVER_UNAVAILABLE error for a remote computer

Tags: windows, winapi, remote-access, rpc

I'm trying to implement rebooting of a remote computer with [InitiateShutdown](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa376872(v=vs.85).aspx) API using the following code, but it fails with `RPC_S_SERVER_UNAVAILABLE` or `1722` error code:

```
//Process is running as administrator

//Select a remote machine to reboot:
//INFO: Tried it with and w/o two opening slashes.
LPCTSTR pServerName = L"192.168.42.105";
//Or use 127.0.0.1 if you don't have access to another machine on your network.
//This will attempt to reboot your local machine.
//In that case make sure to call shutdown /a /m \\127.0.0.1 to cancel it.

if(AdjustPrivilege(NULL, L"SeShutdownPrivilege", TRUE) &&
    AdjustPrivilege(pServerName, L"SeRemoteShutdownPrivilege", TRUE))
{
    int nErrorCode = ::InitiateShutdown(pServerName, NULL, 30,
                                        SHUTDOWN_INSTALL_UPDATES | SHUTDOWN_RESTART, 0);

    //Receive nErrorCode == 1722, or RPC_S_SERVER_UNAVAILABLE
}



BOOL AdjustPrivilege(LPCTSTR pStrMachine, LPCTSTR pPrivilegeName, BOOL bEnable)
{
    HANDLE hToken; 
    TOKEN_PRIVILEGES tkp;
    BOOL bRes = FALSE;

    if(!OpenProcessToken(GetCurrentProcess(), TOKEN_ADJUST_PRIVILEGES | TOKEN_QUERY, &hToken))
        return FALSE; 

    if(LookupPrivilegeValue(pStrMachine, pPrivilegeName, &tkp.Privileges[0].Luid))
    {
        tkp.PrivilegeCount = 1;  
        tkp.Privileges[0].Attributes = bEnable ? SE_PRIVILEGE_ENABLED : SE_PRIVILEGE_REMOVED; 

        bRes = AdjustTokenPrivileges(hToken, FALSE, &tkp, 0, (PTOKEN_PRIVILEGES)NULL, 0);
        int nOSError = GetLastError();
        if(bRes)
        {
            if(nOSError != ERROR_SUCCESS)
                bRes = FALSE;
        }
    }

    CloseHandle(hToken);

    return bRes;
}
```

So to prepare for this code to run I do the following on `this` computer, which is `Windows 7 Pro` (as I would do for the Microsoft's [shutdown](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb491003.aspx) tool):

- Run the following "as administrator" to allow SMB access to the logged in user `D1` on the `192.168.42.105` computer (per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16526680/843732)):

> ```
>  NET USE \\192.168.42.105\IPC$ 1234 /USER:D1
> ```

- Run the process with my code above "as administrator".

And then do the following on remote computer, or `192.168.42.105`, that has `Windows 7 Pro` (per [answer here with most upvotes](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/4cd01733-0f21-4078-979d-5080bc0c98fb/remote-shutdown-access-denied-5)):

- Control Panel, Network and Sharing Center, Change Advanced Sharing settings
  "Private" enable "Turn on File and Printer sharing"
- Set the following key:

  HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System

  LocalAccountTokenFilterPolicy=dword:1
- RUN secpol.msc, then go to Local Security Policy, Security Settings, Local Policies, User Rights Assignment. Add "Everyone" to "Force shutdown from a remote system". (Just remember to remove it after you're done testing!)

Note that the following `shutdown` command seems to work just fine to reboot the remote computer:

```
shutdown /r /m \\192.168.42.105 /t 30
```

What am I missing with my code?

**EDIT:**

OK. I will admit that I was merely interested in why `InitiateShutdown` doesn't seem to "want" to work with a remote server connection, while `InitiateSystemShutdownEx` or `InitiateSystemShutdown` had no issues at all. (Unfortunately the latter two did not have the `dwShutdownFlags` parameter, which I needed to pass the `SHUTDOWN_INSTALL_UPDATES` flag to, which caused my persistence...)

At this point I had no other way of finding out than dusting out a copy of [WinDbg](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/hh852365.aspx)... I'm still trying to dig into it, but so far this is what I found...

(A) It turns out that `InitiateSystemShutdownEx` internally uses a totally different RPC call. W/o too many details, it initiates RPC binding with [RpcStringBindingComposeW](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa378481(v=vs.85).aspx) using the following parameters:

```
   ObjUuid = NULL
   ProtSeq = ncacn_np
   NetworkAddr = \\192.168.42.105
   EndPoint = \\PIPE\\InitShutdown
   Options = NULL
```

or the following binding string:

```
ncacn_np:\\\\192.168.42.105[\\PIPE\\InitShutdown]
```

(B) While `InitiateShutdown` on the other hand uses the following binding parameters:

```
   ObjUuid = 765294ba-60bc-48b8-92e9-89fd77769d91
   ProtSeq = ncacn_ip_tcp
   NetworkAddr = 192.168.42.105
   EndPoint = NULL
   Options = NULL
```

which it later translates into the following binding string:

```
ncacn_np:\\\\192.168.42.105[\\PIPE\\lsarpc]
```

that it uses to obtain the RPC handle that it passes to [WsdrInitiateShutdown](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc245226.aspx) (that seems to have its [own specification](http://hackipedia.org/Protocols/Microsoft%20Windows/Remote%20Shutdown/MS-RSP%20Remote%20Shutdown%20Protocol%20Specification%20(v20080207).pdf)):

[image]

So as you see, the `InitiateShutdown` call is technically treated as `Unknown RPC service` (for the UUID `{765294ba-60bc-48b8-92e9-89fd77769d91}`), which later causes a whole bunch of credential checks between the server and the client:

[image]

which, honestly, I'm not sure I want to step into with a low-level debugger :)

At this stage I will say that I am not very well versed on "Local Security Authority" interface (or the `\PIPE\lsarpc` named pipe configuration.) So if anyone knows what configuration is missing on the server side to allow this RPC call to go through, I would appreciate if you could post your take on it?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101312/discussion-on-question-by-c00000fd-initiateshutdown-fails-with-rpc-s-server-unav).

Comment: I can reproduce the OPs problem; InitiateShutdown does not work for remote machines, even within a domain.  Looks like a Windows bug.

Comment: @HarryJohnston: I'm curious if you were able to get anywhere with it? It seems like it's still not fixed on my Windows 10.

Comment: Nothing to report.